# Regular Expressions in Java (regex)

Tags: java, regex, expression

Can you please help me to write a Java code to replace String with pattern like below

`images/deal/number1/number2-text1.jpg` with `images/deal/number3/number4-text1.jpg` . Text 1 remains same after replacement but could be different for different strings.

e.g. images/deal/1111/222-bonus.jpg should become `images/deal/3333/444-bonus.jpg` or images/deal/5555/666-test.jpg should become `images/deal/7777/888-test.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "images/deal/1111/22222-text1.jpg";
    String num3 = "3333";
    String num4 = "4444";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=.*/)(\\d+/\\d+)", num3 + "/"
            + num4));
}
```

O/P :

```
images/deal/3333/4444-text1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general method that will apply some transformation on the replaced parts, you can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. I suppose here the relation is (as described in your example)

- number3 = number1 + 2222
- number4 = number2 + 222

x

```
static String applyOffset(String num, int offset) {
    int v = Integer.valueOf(num);
    return Integer.toString(v+offset);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    String path = "tata/toto/1111/333-tutu.jpg";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)-(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String path2 = new StringBuffer()
        .append(matcher.group(1))
        .append("/")
        .append(applyOffset(matcher.group(2), 2222))
        .append("/")
        .append(applyOffset(matcher.group(3), 222))
        .append("-")
        .append(matcher.group(4))
        .toString();
        System.out.println(path2);
    }
```

Gives : `tata/toto/4444/555-tutu.jpg`